# Asynchronous http listener c#

Tags: multithreading, http, asynchronous, listener

I am developing a small SMS server in C# and want to make an asynchronous listener that processes requests sent to an SMS object (username, message, etc.). I want to create the asynchronous listener as a class library. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace AListener
{
    public class CAListener
    {
        public CAListener()
        {
            Thread listener = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(RequestListener));
            listener.Start(new string[] { "http://*:11600/" });
        }

        private ManualResetEvent stopListener = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        private object lockListener = new object();
        private bool newRequest = false;

        public void StopListener()
        {
            stopListener.Set();
        }

        public void RequestListener(object parameter)
        {
            string[] prefixes = parameter as string[];

            HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();

            foreach (string prefix in prefixes)
            {
                listener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);
            }

            listener.Start();

            IAsyncResult result = listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(ListenerCallback), listener);

            while (!stopListener.WaitOne(10))
            {
                lock (lockListener)
                {
                    if (newRequest)
                    {
                        result = listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(ListenerCallback), listener);

                        newRequest = false;
                    }
                }

                result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(10);
            }

            listener.Close();
        }

        public void ListenerCallback(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            HttpListener listener = (HttpListener)result.AsyncState;

            // Call EndGetContext to complete the asynchronous operation.
            HttpListenerContext context = listener.EndGetContext(result);

            HttpListenerRequest request = context.Request;

            // Obtain a response object.
            HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

            // Construct a response. 
            string responseString = "<HTML><BODY> Hello world!</BODY></HTML>";
            byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(responseString);

            // Get a response stream and write the response to it.
            response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;

            System.IO.Stream output = response.OutputStream;

            output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

            // You must close the output stream.
            output.Close();

            lock (lockListener)
            {
                newRequest = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a UI form where I obtain AListener object and everything here is OK.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AListener;

namespace ZNSMS
{
    public partial class ZNSMSServer : Form
    {
        public ZNSMSServer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        CAListener ca = null;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ca.StopListener();
        }

        private void ZNSMSServer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ca = new CAListener();
        }
    }
}
```

But when I press the Button (I just want to stop the listener) -  for some reason `listener.Stop()` kills my main UI Form `ZNSMSServer`. When I comment `listener.Stop()` it's working, but I think that's not the proper way and I cannot understand why calling `listener.Stop()` can impact (in this case Close?) the calling object - in this case `ZNSMSServer`.

If anyone has dealt with this kind of issue before, I would really appreciate it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to set `newRequest = false;` before calling `result = listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(ListenerCallback), listener);` otherwise it's possible `newRequest` will remain `false` forever.

Comment: Re the question, what does the (VS?) debugger tell you? You've called `StopListener()` - do you get an exception...?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. This idea with "newRequest = false;" is not actually bad. I guess when you look something so many times you oversee such logic solution. I will try and will share answer. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, although I don't believe that is related to the crash you're seeing.